# How to cut from long N bits to get an int and cout it ( and get readable int)?

Tags: c++, int, bit-manipulation, long-integer

How to cut from long N bits to get an int and cout it ( and get readable int)?
I try

```
    int count = sizeof(long) - sizeof(int);
    int int_val =(long_val>> (sizeof(long) - count));
```

But get some horible cout... What shall I do - how to cut from long N bits to get an int and cout it ( and get readable int)?

Comment: Assuming a `long` is longer than an `int` (which is a bad assumption; they're often the same length), which bits do you want: the high ones or the low ones?

Comment: Note that your shift amount is `sizeof(l) - (sizeof(l) - sizeof(i))`; if `long` is 64 bits and `int` is 32 bits, that is `32`; if `long` and `int` are 32 bits both, the result is _still_ `32`. But in the latter case, that feels wrong...

Comment: [What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve here?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (unoptimized):

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int lowerBits(long in) {
    // use unsigned so that sign bit is not propagated
    // when compiler casts it to a long
    return in & (unsigned) -1;
}

int upperBits(long in) {
    return lowerBits(in >> numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits);
}

int main(int, char **) {
    cout << hex << lowerBits(0x4321432112341234) << endl;
    cout << hex << upperBits(0x4321432112341234) << endl;
}
```

Output on a 64 bit machine, using gcc:

```
12341234
43214321
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the lower N bits, try `(long_val & ((1<<(N-1)) - 1))`

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the original code:

1. The `sizeof` operator works with units of *bytes*, but the `>>` operator works with units of *bits*.
2. You're shifting by `sizeof(long) - sizeof(long) + sizeof(int)`, which could only be correct by accident.

If you want to get the low-order bytes in a portable way, you can use:

```
unsigned int_val = (unsigned) (long_val & UINT_MAX);
```